# ip address hack

Tags: ip, surveillance

I believe someone knows my IP through accessing public WiFi and accounts such as BT sport.

Now I know I'm being monitored but not sure how.
I believe this person is a hacker and that they know the latest activity on my phone and laptop.

I'm taking the issue further and possibly have a good image of who they are but obviously cannot suspect them.

I have a Toshiba laptop.

Comment: IP Addresses dont work like that.

Comment: How are you so certain you're being hacked? can you give details? IP's don't work like this man. 
Just knowing your IP is not enough to monitor someone's traffic. They would need to be sniffing it, by compromising your edge router, malware/spyware installed on your laptop and phone, etc. 
How can someone know your IP when you are on different public wifi spots? I assume your IP is dynamic given by your ISP and is renewed every so often or by a reboot of the router. How can they know your IP from BT sport? Do they have BT sports compromised as well?

Comment: You have not actually asked a question. You have also not provided details. We can't help unless you can be more specific about the details and ask an actual question.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is probably flawed cause:

**a)** Your IP address (specifically, the external/public one), changes every time you change from one internet connection (like a coffee shop wifi) to another (your home), and that IP, commonly represents the entire network of computers connected to the coffee shop. And as a note, knowing someone's IP address, is simple, and normally is not a security risk. (There are exceptions) 
**b)** Knowing that, viruses and trojans are very common, but specifically targeted spyware (Spy software targeted at a specific person), are not.

If you still suspect being targeted by a hacker, or being spied with malicious software, I would suggest:
a) Consider formatting your computer
b) Use a Antivirus solution, and do scans often. (Check **[AVTest](https://www.av-test.org/en/)** for insight on which av you should choose)
 
c) Keep your computer, programs and others UPDATED, this is very important.
d) Watch out for **phishing** emails. (This means, seemingly legitimate emails trying to fool you into giving login credentials, or downloading malicious software) 
e) **Don't** use public Wi-Fi networks, hackers can use public hotspots to tap into internet requests, in order to spy on traffic, or even get passwords. (History)

PD: Can you please tell me, what have you noticed on your PC that makes you believe you are being spied? Be more specific.

Comment: OK so A month or two I actually did find a trojan win 32 dynamasta and removed it I believe using malware anti bytes

Comment: The other my laptop touch pad was moving crazy weird I booted and this fixed it now my win 10 cursor is flickering heavy I know I'm being watches maybe not everything but certainly browser wise I also found my IP at a public computer cafe by cmd run ipconfig. Look I'm certain

Comment: Someone offered me a BT WiFi log in called ervis@null.net jorgen2001 to watch football I'm sure ever since

Comment: I am with talk talk and I have lost phones before connected to my wifi